# How to run python macros in LibreOffice?

Tags: python, ubuntu, macros, libreoffice, ubuntu-13.10

When I go to **Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> Python** I get this dialog:

[image]

It is **not possible** to create new Python macros.

Apparently LibreOffice has **no Python editor** so I have to write the macros elsewhere and then just execute them.

But I do not know **where** to put the Python scripts.

I tried a system-wide search for files with **"HeloWorld"** in their name and I got no results.

I tried to put a **test.py** file into:

```
/home/martin/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts
```

and reload the application, but the **test** macro is not shown.

I tried to find the appropriate setting in **Tools -> Options -> Path** but there is no **"path to macros"**:

[image]

How can I run Python macros from LibreOffice?

This question is a part of my quest to learn Python and to learn LibreOffice macros, so any link to a general tutorial is welcomed. The tutorials on **LibreOffice Python macros** seem to be especially hard to find.

I am using **LibreOffice Version: 4.1.3.2**

Comment: Try to manually make a subdirectory `python` (all lowercase) inside `/home/martin/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts` and put your script there.

Comment: Good to help you :) Addendum: This advice is based on https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language

Comment: Thanks, reported: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126390

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to manually make a subdirectory `python` (all lowercase) inside `/home/martin/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts` and put your script there.

This is based on [this wiki.openoffice.org documentations](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language).

Comment: Does libreoffice provide similar documentation? Is there any difference between libreoffice and openoffice?

Comment: The documentation works for LibreOffice as well.  There are very few differences, similar to differences between one version of LibreOffice and another.

Answer (score 5):

I also struggled to get a clear start, so I documented my setup and the things I learned [here](https://onesheep.org/insights/scripting-libreoffice-with-python). If you work through that, you will see that you can place your python script in any folder as long as you link to it correctly.

**EDIT:** The old URL-only answer now points to a dead link. That page can still be found on the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216111607/https://onesheep.org/scripting-libreoffice-python/) or [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/58d401c9b9ed5d80f60deee88d1fcdfd).

Comment: This says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I guess this is why "link-only" answers are [not considered as answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2388257), and I'm flagging it as such.

Comment: The OP specifically asks for "any link to a general tutorial", so in this case a proper answer can be a link, right?

Comment: Dear Jannie, I moved your post to this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/58d401c9b9ed5d80f60deee88d1fcdfd). Any chance that I can find you on Twitter?

Answer (score 3):

Python scripts are located on `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/scripts/python`

Maybe [this tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) will help, as it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Install the new [APSO extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python)
2. then go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize python scripts*.
3. Now, select "My Macros" and choose *Menu -> Create Module*.

[This documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python) helped me the most.

Answer (score -1):

for a short intro on how to run python macros in LibreOffice Calc, you may check [Python Macros in LibreCalc](https://www.arunkhattri.org/posts/python_macros/)